# He has come to see if I was/were ok - indicative or subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives

I know that the subjunctive is used in formal English in some imaginary situations, such as conditions, wishes (after "to wish", but strangely not after "to hope"), assumptions (eg after "to suppose"), suggestions, statements of necessity, etc. Examples:

- If I were rich, ...
- I wish the computer were working.
- Suppose that I were there now.
- I suggest that he implement a budget cut in March.
- It is essential that she be present.

Does this apply to a condition related to a verb? Which one of the following sentences is correct?

- He has come to see if I was ok. (indicative mood)
- He has come to see if I were ok.  (subjunctive mood)

Comment: Neither of your sentences are idiomatic. It should be *he has come to see if I **am** okay*. Your well being is a present situation. You also can't use the subjunctive, because you're not describing a hypothetical.

Comment: Why a present situation? He came in a specific moment in the past to see if I was ok back then. In the present: he comes to see if I am ok.

Comment: What is the definition of a hypothetical? My sentence has a condition ("if I am/was ok"). Are both concepts distinct?

Comment: Your first example requires present tense "am" (not "was"). And in your second, irrealis "were" is totally inappropriate for two reasons: first, it does not express modality and second "if I was OK" is an interrogative (embedded question), and such clauses don't normally occur with irrealis "were".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista It would only be in the past if the sentence started with *came* or *had come*. But since it starts with ***has*** *come*, it's still happening. *He **has** a cold* is present; *he **had** a cold* is past. And since you *know* he has come, his being there is a fact, not a supposition.

Comment: @JasonBassford AFAIK the Present Perfect expresses a fact/event that happened in an inexact time *of the past* and that has a relationship with the present (ex: I have done my homework, I have forgotten my bag, I have been to Australia). "to have a relationship with the present" does not mean that it is still happening, as one can see from the previous examples. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista The example sentences in your question use an auxiliary verb followed by the bare infinitive of *to come*. If it were possible to follow the same construction in your latest examples (it's not), it would be *I **have do** my homework.* The particular verbs and construction you use in your question refer to the present. I can't provide that as an answer, however, because it's not what you're actually asking. But you do need to choose a different set of example sentences. I am going to stop arguing about them being wrong in comments now.